# AVAudioPlayer issue (music file is not playing in background mode if the device is locked )

Tags: ios, background, avaudioplayer

if the device is not locked then music is playing in background.I've pasted the code in .Plist file as well here is the code i have used

```
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:saveFileName];
    NSURL *url1 = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath: path];
    appdelegate.sharedplayer=[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url1 error:NULL];
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive: YES error: nil];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];

    [appdelegate.sharedplayer setVolume:appdelegate.volumeDelegate];

    [appdelegate.sharedplayer play];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apple iOS restrict data access when device is locked in password.
so you convert NSDocumetDirectory to arry of NSData of songs. And assign AVAudioPlayer it work.

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:saveFileName];
NSURL *url1 = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath: path];
NSData *data=[[NSData alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:url1];
appdelegate.sharedplayer=[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:data error:nil];
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive: YES error: nil];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];
[appdelegate.sharedplayer setVolume:appdelegate.volumeDelegate];
[appdelegate.sharedplayer play];
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to do  some  changes in plist file.

a-set your Apps does not run in background 
b-Set background mode to App plays audio

use this code in  `AppDelege`

```
NSError *setCategoryErr = nil;
    NSError *activationErr  = nil;
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:&setCategoryErr];
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:YES error:&activationErr];
```

Comment: Sport I did what ever you said,I pasted the code you have send, in my app delegate.m DidEnterBackground & DidFinishLaunching WithOptions and also in .Plist file its not working

Comment: "Sport": the solution which Selvam Suggested is working fine but for music player we need to run in background but the password lock doesn't allow us to retrieve files from our application document folder

Answer (score -1):

Try to set this in your project.plist

[image: set this in your plist]