# AVAudioPlayer Issue (If device is locked with password, Apple does not allow us to retrive data from our Documentry)

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7, avaudioplayer

I'm developing a music player application if the device is not locked with out password lock we can able to play music in background. Else Apple doesn't allow us to access files through URL from documents directory. Did any one faced this same issue ?

Now i am storing the entire songs index in NSData and store those NSData in to NSArray during run time but if files are more then the application encounters memory issue and crashes the app.

If any one have alternate solution please let me know ...

Visit the below Link for my code sample

[AVAudioPlayer issue (music file is not playing in background mode if the device is locked )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19959590/avaudioplayer-issue-music-file-is-not-playing-in-background-mode-if-the-device)

Comment: So you posted this, linked back to your previous question, *and* flagged this for moderator attention with the same link to your previous question... what do you want us to do?

Comment: Apologies, i just wanted to know whether anybody faced this issue. So that i will get the help to fix the problem.

Comment: If this is intended to bring attention to your previous question and not a separate question, please don't do that.